# Change resources path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm using Rails 4

I have a routes.rb file that looks like:

```
resources :books
```

However, I'd like the urls in the application to end up looking like `/b/101` instead of `/books/101`.

I realize I could go through and rename each resource path individually, but is there not a way to do this by changing the `resources` somehow? Kind of like how you can change the params by doing `resources :books, params: :new_id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
resources :books, path: 'b'
```